# Kafka one consumer with two different checkpoints

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka consumer project which consumes data from a specific Kafka topic. The 90% of the records are processed as soon as I got them but I have the delay processing some of the records (10%).

This these records need to be delayed, I can't commit the records so it may cause Kafka to reassign the partitions to new nodes. In order to avoid that, I can read the same topic twice and delay the fetching data part in the second consumer but it requires deserialization twice so comes with an overhead.

Is it possible the read records using single consumer but have two separate commits with Kafka consumers? It will be basically similar to having two different consumers in terms of commit, `consumer.poll` will be called from a single consumer but there will be two `consumer.commitSync` for each batch. I will help me to avoid extra deserialization and also the network cost.

Comment: Is it possible to put those 10% records into a separate topic?

Comment: @amethystic Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned are the things you can do to achieve the above-mentioned task.

- Create a pipe Line having two topics(T1, T2) push all the messages (90%) in topic T1 and rest all the messages  10% in topic T2.
- Make your Kafka consumer configurable i.e. you can easily pass polling interval, batchSize, and batch timeout whenever you are starting your consumer.
- Find a logic/ or if your second topic consumption is time-based then schedule the cron which will start and stop your consumer topic T2 when it is required.
- Regarding consumer Groups, you can place both of your topics in the same group or indifferent. It's completely your choice.

By this way you will be keeping the topics clean.and each and every time you need to process the messages you can do it easily by setting up the pipeline just for once.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have control over how the data is put in Kafka topic. :/

Comment: @burakemre Then how to distribute the data between 10% and 90% ?